# Load/read json from URL Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm new in JavaScript, I wan' to read JSON information from a URL, this http://www.imobiliare.ro/sugestii/hunedoara

Until now i've done to parse information in a static way, by copy what I recive when I acces that URL

Looks like this:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>


var text1 = '{"sugestii":[{"nume":"Hunedoara (tot jude&#355;ul)","id":"123220","tip":2},{"nume":"Hunedoara (din jude&#355;ul Hunedoara)","id":"126958","tip":1},{"nume":"Hunedoara Timisana (din jude&#355;ul Arad)","id":"14257","tip":1}]}' ;


obj = JSON.parse(text1);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.sugestii[0].nume+ " ," + obj.sugestii[0].id+", " + obj.sugestii[0].tip;
</script>
```

How Can I make something like his

```
var text1 = "http://www.imobiliare.ro/sugestii/Hunedoara";
```

Comment: Vanilla JS, or can you use a library like jQuery?

Comment: I can't use any liberary....that is my task to create one

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Comment: Does the URL is in same domain you are requesting from?